# How to change the default path of the Prometheus exporter in OpenTelemetry Collector?

Tags: configuration, prometheus, metrics, open-telemetry, exporter

I am using OpenTelemetry Collector to collect and export metrics from my application. I want to use the Prometheus exporter to expose my metrics on collector's endpoint which then can be scraped by prometheus, but I need to change the default path of the exporter from /metrics to /v1/metrics. How can I do that?

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc: 
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4317"

exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:10000"

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      exporters: [ prometheus ]
```

I have read the documentation of the Prometheus exporter, but I could not find any option to configure the path. I also searched on Google and Stack Overflow, but I did not find any relevant answers.

Is there a way to change the path of the Prometheus exporter in OpenTelemetry Collector? If so, how can I do it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**What I have already tried:**

when I try to try pass the path through the endpoint:

```
exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: '0.0.0.0:10000/v1/metrics'
```

this is the error I receive:

```
Error: cannot start pipelines: listen tcp: address tcp/10000/v1/metrics: unknown port
2023/09/26 10:51:50 collector server run finished with error: cannot start pipelines: listen tcp: address tcp/10000/v1/metrics: unknown port
```

Comment: Trying to understand: are you saying that setting `endpoint: "0.0.0.0:10000/v1/metrics"` does not work?

Comment: Dear @MichaelHausenblas, yes when I try to configure the endpoint the way you mentioned this is the error i receive:

`Error: cannot start pipelines: listen tcp: address tcp/10000/v1/metrics: unknown port
2023/09/26 10:51:50 collector server run finished with error: cannot start pipelines: listen tcp: address tcp/10000/v1/metrics: unknown port`

Comment: Okay, thanks and, just to make sure we’re not hitting some YAML quirks, can you try it without ' that is the raw string?

Comment: Of course, tried it three different ways :) single quote, double quote and without anything. still produces the same error.
please let me know if there is anything else that I can try and do to test this. 
I appreciate your help @MichaelHausenblas .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use the Prometheus exporter to send metrics to a Prometheus backend

`prometheus` exporter doesn't send metrics to Prometheus backend (this exporter only exposes metrics on the collector's endpoint, where path `/metrics` is not configurable). You need `prometheusremotewrite` exporter, which sends metrics to Prometheus backend, e.g.:

```
exporters:
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: "https://my-cortex:7900/api/v1/push"
```

Doc: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/prometheusremotewriteexporter

Update:

As I said path `/metrics` in `prometheus` exporter is not configurable - it is hardcoded. See https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/5133f4ccd69fa40d016c5b7f2198fb6ac61007b4/exporter/prometheusexporter/prometheus.go#L69

So you can't expose your metrics on custom path, e.g. `/v1/metrics`.

The only way is that you will create own fork of `prometheus` exporter (and then build own collector), where you will implement own requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Jan. Excuse my poor wording here. what I meant to say is that I want to expose my metrics on the collector's endpoint. I will edit my question to clarify it.

Comment: @SepanD answer updated

Comment: Well I was kind of hoping not to hear this :). thank you so much for your time and effort @Jan.

Comment: @SepanD I would say you are doing something wrong when you need `/v1/metrics` path for prometheus exporter. More native otel approach is pushing metrics with prometheusremotewrite exporter. BTW: `/v1/metrics` is default OTLP metric endpoint, so maybe you are mixing it with otlp/otel.

Comment: tbh I was looking for a way to natively collect metrics from multiple software components and expose them on a server to then be accessed from my frontend. Otel is great for the first part of this problem but the only way I found to then expose the collected metrics on a http server was by using its prometheus exporter feature. I will be more than happy if you could suggest a better solution for my problem @Jan.